# How to find specifics values in a dictionary for repeated headings of the same name?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have created a dictionary named "city_metrics" which contain headers such as City, Country, Population, Area. In my dictionary, there are 3 City, 3 Population and 3 Are.

```
city_metrics =
[{'City': 'Santiago',
  'Country': 'Dominican Republic',
  'Population': 900000,
  'Area': 4758},
 {'City': 'Montreal',
  'Country': 'Canada',
  'Population': 345000,
  'Area': 2731571},
 {'City': 'Seoul',
  'Country': 'South Korea',
  'Population': 234540,
  'Area': 3454},
 {'City': 'Marakesh', 
 'Country': 'Morocco', 
 'Population': 928850,
 'Area': 200}]
```

How can I list only the Population from this dictionary? Is there a different approach besides typing all these lines?

```
print city_metrics[0]['Population']

print city_metrics[1]['Population']

print city_metrics[2]['Population']

print city_metrics[3[['Population']
```

Comment: this --> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements is a great place to start

Comment: ```city_matrics``` is not a dictionary. It is a list of dictionaries, which is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of populations by doing the following.

```
populations = [city['Population'] for city in city_metrics]
```

Alternatively, you can do a `for loop` in which you print the city name and the population.

```
for city in city_metrics:
    print(city['Population'])
```

You may also want to format your answer in a way that makes sense like by printing the city name and population.

```
cities_and_pops = [f"The population of {city['City']} is {city['Population']}." for city in city_metrics]
cities_and_pops
>>>['The population of Santiago is 900000.',
 'The population of Montreal is 345000.',
 'The population of Seoul is 234540.',
 'The population of Marakesh is 928850.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over your list this way:

```
metrics = [
    {'City': 'Santiago', 'Country': 'Dominican Republic', 'Population': 900000, 'Area': 4758}, 
    {'City': 'Montreal', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 345000, 'Area': 2731571},
    {'City': 'Seoul', 'Country': 'South Korea', 'Population': 234540, 'Area': 3454},
    {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200}
]

for metric in metrics:
    print(metric['City'], metric['Population'])
```

Another approach would be a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
cities = {
    'Santiago': {'Country': 'Dominican Republic', 'Population': 900000, 'Area': 4758}, 
    'Montreal': {'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 345000, 'Area': 2731571},
    'Seoul': {'Country': 'South Korea', 'Population': 234540, 'Area': 3454},
    'Marakesh': {'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200}
}
```

Using that kind of structure, you could do things like this:

```
print(cities['Montreal']['Population'])
```

Or iterate over cities like this:

```
for city in cities:
    print(city, cities[city]['Population'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
city_metrics = [
    {'City': 'Santiago', 'Country': 'Dominican Republic', 'Population': 900000, 'Area': 4758},
    {'City': 'Montreal', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 345000, 'Area': 2731571},
    {'City': 'Seoul', 'Country': 'South Korea', 'Population': 234540, 'Area': 3454},
    {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200}
]

for i in city_metrics:
    print(i['City'],i["Population"])
```

this should do it for you. if you need to print keys. just pass dictionary .items